# C++: Pass a function from one function to another

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm trying to implement a quicksort algorithm to sort an array filled with objects of type "Movie" by one of 4 different criteria. Each movie object contains a ranking, number of votes, rating, and the name of the movie. I've also written 4 static bool functions within the class definition that takes in two movie object references and returns true if the first one is smaller, or returns false if it is larger.

Ex:

```
bool Movie::GetLowerRank(const Movie& x, const Movie& y){
    if (x.rank < y.rank)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Like I said I'm trying to implement a quicksort algorithm that will sort the array based on the user preference. I want to pass in one of my 4 sorting functions to my quicksort function, similar to how vectors sort works. My problem is that I have two quicksort functions, the recursive and the base:

```
void quickSort(Movie array[], int min, int max, bool (*compare_function)(Movie&, Movie&)){
    if (min < max) {
        int pivot_i = (min + max)/2;
        int pivot_i2 = quickSort(array, min, max, pivot_i, compare_function);
        quickSort(array, min, pivot_i2 - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivot_i2 +1, max);
    }   
}

int quickSort(Movie array[], int min, int max, int pivot, bool (*compare_function)(Movie& a, Movie& b)){
    Movie pivot_entry = array[pivot];
    swap (array[pivot], array[max]);
    int pivot_final_index = min;
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        if(compare_function(array[i], pivot_entry)){
            swap(array[i], array[pivot_final_index]);
            ++pivot_final_index;
        }
    }
    swap(array[max], array[pivot_final_index]);
    return pivot_final_index;
}
```

I've tried to add the function parameter to the parameter list but I can't figure out how to have the void quickSort pass the function (which is obtained in the main) to the int quickSort which actually utilizes it.

Comment: Has your `void quickSort` seen a prototype for your `int quickSort` before it tries to call it ?

Comment: Is your GetLowerRank function static?

Comment: There's a discrepancy between your actual function which takes two `const Movie&` and the `quickSort` prototypes which take two `Movie&`.

Comment: You could save yourself the trouble with implementation and use `std::sort` (the overload which takes a custom predicate).

Comment: Yes, all bool comparing functions are static. And thanks for pointing out the discrepancy, I've fixed both of them. I know I could just use the STL algorithms but I'd like to try implementing this just for my own understanding and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

First simplify `GetLowerRank` to

```
bool Movie::GetLowerRank(const Movie& x, const Movie& y) {
    return x.rank < y.rank;
}
```

The `compare_function` is just passed as the last parameter to `quickSort`. Since `void quickSort(...)` calls `int quickSort(...)`, you must declare or define `int quickSort()`  first, of course. Otherwise `void quickSort()` tries to call itself and will complain about number of arguments mismatch

```
int quickSort(Movie array[], int min, int max, int pivot, bool (*compare_function)(Movie& a, Movie& b)){
    Movie pivot_entry = array[pivot];
    swap (array[pivot], array[max]);
    int pivot_final_index = min;
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        if(compare_function(array[i], pivot_entry)){
            swap(array[i], array[pivot_final_index]);
            ++pivot_final_index;
        }
    }
    swap(array[max], array[pivot_final_index]);
    return pivot_final_index;
}

void quickSort(Movie array[], int min, int max, bool (*compare_function)(Movie&, Movie&)){
    if (min < max) {
        int pivot_i = (min + max)/2;
        int pivot_i2 = quickSort(array, min, max, pivot_i, compare_function);
        quickSort(array, min, pivot_i2 - 1, compare_function);
        quickSort(array, pivot_i2 +1, max, compare_function);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive calls in the first quickSort appear to have been called without using the function pointer:

```
    quickSort(array, min, pivot_i2 - 1);
    quickSort(array, pivot_i2 +1, max);
```

---

The code below  uses function pointers and will compile:

NOTE: int has been substituted for Movie:

If there is still an error with `Movie` it's a GOOD idea, even 
if not strictly necessary to verify

```
(1) the assignment operator and 
(2) copy constructor and 
(3) equality operator
```

(all three) are defined for Movie (you may already know this).

```
void quickSort(int array[], int min, int max, bool (*compare_function)(int&, int&));

int quickSort(int array[], int min, int max, int pivot, bool (*compare_function)(int& a, int& b));

void swap(int array[], int a, int b);


void swap(int array[], int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    if (array != NULL) {
        temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;

    }

}

void quickSort(int array[], int min, int max, bool (*compare_function)(int&, int&)){

    if (min < max) {

        int pivot_i = (min + max)/2;
        int pivot_i2 = quickSort(array, min, max, pivot_i, compare_function);
        quickSort(array, min, pivot_i2 - 1, compare_function);
        quickSort(array, pivot_i2 +1, max, compare_function);
    }   
}

int quickSort(int array[], int min, int max, int pivot, 
    bool (*compare_function)(int& a, int& b)){

    int pivot_entry = array[pivot];

    swap (array, pivot, max);

    int pivot_final_index = min;

    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        if(compare_function(array[i], pivot_entry)){
            swap(array, i, pivot_final_index);
            ++pivot_final_index;
        }
    }
    swap(array, max, pivot_final_index);
    return pivot_final_index;
}
```